# Getting values with regular expressions from a string;

Tags: regex

I have a string like this:

> Some calculations income:11111.11 com:11.11 outgo:22222.22 com:22.22 cancel:33333.33 com:333.33

The order of the income, the outgo and the cancel parts can be different.

I need to get the sum of the income and the related commission

and the outgo and it's commission

and also the canceled sum and it's commission

Now I do it in this way :
first I get the string **income:11111.11 com:11.11** with expression `income:.*?com:(\-){0,1}[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.]+` after that I get the substring **income:11111.11** and then I get the sum

and so on

I think there must be a better way to do it. Can someone tell me how to?

Comment: Which language?

Comment: It is a valid way and is probably the only one since regexps are meant to extract strings of text and do not sum the values found.

Comment: `(\w+:\d+) (com:\d+)` selects your `income:1111 com:11` far easier in 2 groups you can then split on `:`.

Comment: For the new sample string posted, change the regex to ```(\w+:[\d.]+)\s(com:[\d.]+)```.

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't specify which language you are using, here is a way to get the pairs (item/comission) in Python:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 12 2019, 14:45:07) 
[GCC 9.1.1 20190605 (Red Hat 9.1.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> s='Some calculations income:11111 com:11 outgo:22222 com:22 cancel:33333 com:333'
>>> pairs = re.compile(r'(\w+:\d+)\s(com:\d+)')
>>> pprint(pairs.findall(s))
[('income:11111', 'com:11'),
 ('outgo:22222', 'com:22'),
 ('cancel:33333', 'com:333')]
>>>
```

The regex here is just `(\w+:\d+)\s(com:\d+)`.

If you have float numbers on the right side of the key:value pairs, then change the regex to `(\w+:[\d.]+)\s(com:[\d.]+)`:

```
>>> s='Some calculations income:11111.11 com:11.11 outgo:22222.22 com:22.22 cancel:33333.33 com:333.33'
>>> pairs = re.compile(r'(\w+:[\d.]+)\s(com:[\d.]+)')
>>> pprint(pairs.findall(s))
[('income:11111.11', 'com:11.11'),
 ('outgo:22222.22', 'com:22.22'),
 ('cancel:33333.33', 'com:333.33')]
>>>
```

Calculations depend on what language you are using.

Since you already have a list of the pairs, you just need to split them on `:`, convert the right value to `float` and then do the calculations.

Comment: Alright. For the new string posted, change the regex to ```(\w+:[\d.]+)\s(com:[\d.]+)```.